# Flexbox Accordion style

Tags: javascript, css

I wanted to redesign this Flexbox Accordion:
https://codepen.io/arjancodes/pen/gbweYB

```
  .section-content {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .25s .1s ease-out;
  }
}
```

It was displayed vertically, not horizontally as it is now.
How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

add `flex-direction:column` in css

```
.section-content {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction:column;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .25s .1s ease-out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `flex-direction:column` to the blue box and remove  `transform: rotate(-90deg);` in klasa 5 and klasa 6

Comment: I tried adding this to flex-direction:column in li {},
but its doestn work
. Check for yourself on the page:
https://codepen.io/arjancodes/pen/gbweYB

Comment: add `flex-direction:column ` in ul not in li